# String Search, x86 Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I'm having difficulties with a certain homework problem in my assembly class. The book and tutorials I have watched didn't help me figure it out so I thought I'd come here. Here's the assignment.

> "Write a inline assembly language program subroutine that searches for
>   a character in a string and returns the first occurrence of the
>   character in the string.
>
> The subroutine must be called search and the string is passed in the
>   ESI register.  The character to search for should be placed in the AL
>   register and the length of the string is in the ECX register.
>
> The subroutine should return the location of the character in the EBX
>   register, where the first character is 1 and if not found, returns 0.
>
> For example, given a 10 character string in mystring = 'EXCELLENTE',
>   locate the first 'X' character.
>
> ```
> lea ESI,mystring
> mov al,'X'
> mov ecx,10
> call search
> ------returns with EBX =2
> lea ESI,mystring
> mov al,'Y'
> mov ecx,10
> call search
> ------returns EBX = 0
> ```
>
> The program must work for any sized string or character combination"

I understand subroutines just fine and have recently learned the repne scasb function. I believe I might have to use that, but I am completely unsure. Also why did my professor use the ESI register in his example? I thought that one was specifically for memory locations. This is the first code I have had to write involving string manipulation and it's just flying right over my head. Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: So, what is your mental image of string in memory? Why don't you try empty "search" in debugger, and just take a look how the string looks in memory view? Anyway, the `esi` is just 32b register, you can use it in any way you wish. But the professor **is** actually using it for memory location. Of the first character of string. So working out my first suggestion will also explain why "esi", and how `scasb` relates to this.

Comment: If thinking of it as a "string" is confusing, just think of it as an array of single-byte values, because that's the same thing.  Anyway, read the instruction-set ref manual for [REPNE SCASB](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html).

Comment: Okay, thinking of strings as arrays does help me out. So theoretically if I were to move "Cellar" into the di register and "e" into the AL register and used repne scasb would the result be two? If so what register would the result be placed in? AL?

Comment: Check instruction reference guide for exact description of `scasb` (and other "string" instructions). What registers and flags are affected. IIRC `scasb` uses `esi` as source address, and `repne` will exit when `ecx` is zero, or ZF (ZeroFlag) is set, which idicates "equal" state. At exit the `esi` will point either at found char or one beyond? I don't know from head, so go to my first sentence. To get index you subtract original address from it (store it before search in other reg).

Comment: The string is an array of bytes in memory (not as you suggested in a register directly, di isn't big enough and isn't addressable as a memory location).  What your program needs to do is build a pointer to the first character of the string, then walk that pointer along the string character by character, to see if the pointed-to character matches the contents of AL.  The homework assignment scaffold the professor provided sets up the pointer for you, in the ESI register.  You need to write code that walks ESI along the string and does the tests.  I suggest you solve the problem twice...

Comment: ... once by writing explicit machine instructions to do this (take heart, this is pretty short), and then after you have done that, look at repne scasb carefully to see what it does (a pleasant surprise awaits).

Answer (score 0):

This is my SEARCH routine implementation:

```
@Search:Push   EDI     ; Save EDI register

        Mov    EDI,ESI ; ScaS uses the EDI register
        Mov    EBX,ECX ; Save ECX register into output register

        ClD            ; Clear string direction flag

        Cmp    ECX,1   ; Prevent ECX=0 case
        RepNE  ScaSB   ; Search AL for ECX Byte in [EDI]
        CMovNE ECX,EBX ; If not found AL, set ECX to his old value
        Sub    EBX,ECX ; Process AL position; EBX=0 if AL not found

        Pop    EDI     ; Restore EDI register

        Ret            ; Return from subroutine
```